# jQuery mouseover and toggle problem

Tags: jquery, toggle, mouseover, show-hide

I am trying to have a link appear on mouseover and when clicked, have the link toggle a div (show/hide). What I have now is below.

PHP:

```
<li class="test">    <div class="link" style="display:none">
                <span class="toggle"><a href="#">link</a></span>
                                    </div>
    <div class="togglediv"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
</li>
```

JQUERY:

```
    <script language="javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                  $('.test').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){

                      var fade_type = e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut';
                      $(this).find('.link')[fade_type]();

                  }).find('.toggle a').click(function($){
$(".togglediv").hide();
      $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
    });
    });
    </script>
```

The mouseover works, but the toggle doesen't. When I click the link, nothing happens. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/JE8Bz/

1) as the problem T.J. Crowder mentioned

2) you put a $ in the param of  `click()` function

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that. :-)

Comment: I couldn't see that too. But just can't figure out why the hide() doesnt work in jsfiddle so tried to look at it.

Comment: So close, but for some reason the toggle goes on and off by itself when clicking the link, in other words, when I click it the <div class="togglediv"> flickers between show and hide.

Comment: We were just trying to make your code work. If you just want to toggle display of the togglediv, just comment out the code $(".togglediv").hide(); in your click() handler

Comment: I appreciate all the help, but the flickering still happens. When the link is clicked the div shows and hides forever on its own. I just don't get why.

Comment: That should be some other code not listed in this question, as I cannot see any flickering in the demo http://jsfiddle.net/JE8Bz/1/

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing it's a conflict issue with some other code. I'll inspect further, but I marked yours as a right answer since, well, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your link has no next sibling (it's the only thing inside the `span`, which is the only thing in the `div`), so calling `next` on it will return an empty set. Perhaps use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to go up to the containing div, then `next` to go over:

```
$(this).toggleClass("active").closest('div').next().slideToggle("slow");
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no cigar. I just get `http://domain.com/#` when clicking the link.

Comment: @Andrew: See [Quincy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509622/jquery-mouseover-and-toggle-problem/5509856#5509856), there was a second problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/MeAnJ/9/

Update the Fiddle

Comment: It's working, thank you very much. But how can I make it more dynamic, meaning that I have a very large list of list-items where this function should be present?

Comment: writing `<a href="javascript:ToggleDivs('1')">+</a>` for them all can't be good...

Comment: I did write it so that you could change the 1 to any number, then give the corresponding div an id of 'ToggleDiv' then the number.  Anything else, and it seems like a different question

Comment: Yeah I understand, I explained myself badly, because what I meant was that the list-items are generated dynamically so the corresponding divs should be also.

Comment: You can generate both, but if the div's are the exact same, another method would work more efficiently.  Otherwise, I can show you some basic php to generate them.